# Is it possible to have a converter for a List?

Tags: playorm

I want to have the following field in my nosql mapped entity:

private List cookieIds;

Can I have a converter for a list? How would data be saved in Casssandra in this case?

Any hints on how to write a custom converter would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL, we are implementing the @NoSqlEmbedded tag that takes care of that, but it's not complete just yet as I am trying to make it so I can do recursion as well(think heirarchy of @NoSqlEmbedded.)  We have scanning done but need to implement marhsalling/unmarshalling.

**NOTE: I will try to have @NoSqlEmbedded done by end of this weekend with unit tests.**

Every item in the list has to be unique(ie. it is actually a Set not a List then).  Then let's say you have this

```
public Request {
   @NoSqlId
   private String id;
   @NoSqlEmbedded
   private List<String> cookieIds;
   private String property1;
}
```

It will be stored like this

rowkey(id) -> property1="something", cookieIds:cookieValue1=null, cookieIds:cookieValue2=null, cookieIds:cookieValue3=null

So, now we should tell you the reason we don't store it like this....

rowkey(id) -> property1="something", cookieIds=cookieValue1, cookieValue2, cookieValue3

It turns out if you have two machines read in the Request here, and one machine adds cookieValue4 and another machine removes cookieValueValue2, in our implementation you correctly end up with cookieValue1, cookieValue3, cookieValue4 where if we stored it like the second version, ONE of the servers would win so you end up with ONE of these two results(when ideally you want the one removal and one addition to work independently)

- cookieValue1, cookieValue2, cookieValue3, cookieValue4
- cookieValue1, cookieValue3

I hope that makes sense.  NOW, without the @NoSqlEmbedded tag you could use that second method and have a Converter just like I replied in your Date post.  If you write the Date converter, I think you will understand how to do it for this.  Try the Date converter first as practice.

Let me know if you still have questions after that though.

Dean